# How do I fix "BINDING form is not a proper list" error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new in lisp, I'm trying to define a simple function that search an element in a list. 
I'm not finding myself comfortable with the sintax of the language, also I don't quite understand the error/warning messages.

```
(defun in-list (x l)
  (let y (car l))
  (let z (cdr l))
  (if (null l)
      nil
    (if (equal x y)
        t
      (in-list x z)
      )
    )
)
```

I also tried to replace let with seq, but still gave me warnings on "variables assumed to be special".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the syntax of `let`. The [correct form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm#let) is:

```
(let ((var1 exp1)
      (var2 exp2)
      ...
      (varn expn))
  body-of-let)
```

So you should write:

```
(defun in-list (x l)
  (let ((y (car l))
        (z (cdr l)))
    (if (null l)
        nil
        (if (equal x y)
            t
            (in-list x z)))))
```

Note that it is not necessary define the two local variables since the corresponding expression is used only once, so you could abbreviate the function in this way:

```
(defun in-list (x l)
  (if (null l)
      nil
      (if (equal x (car l))
          t
          (in-list x (cdr l)))))
```

and, since you have three different cases in the body, you could use a single `cond` instead of two `if`:

```
(defun in-list (x l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((equal x (car l)) t)
        (t (in-list x (cdr l)))))
```

There are very good free books on the web to learn the basis of the language. See for instance [this one](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `setq`, you can declare your function's inner variables after the `&aux` keyword in the function's lambda-list:

```
(defun in-list (x l &aux y z) 
    (setq y (car l) 
          z (cdr l)) 
    (and l 
         (or (equal x y) 
             (in-list x z))))
```

A better style is to give the auxiliary variables their values right at the point of declaration:

```
(defun in-list (x l &aux (y (car l)) (z (cdr l)))
    (and l 
         (or (equal x y) 
             (in-list x z))))
```

Comment: While technically true, this is not good style.  The `&aux` basically hides another `let*` in the lambda list, which has its uses, but please, not just to declare variables to immediately setq.

Comment: Common Lisp is not Scheme. :) besides, having re-read what I wrote here, this answer does not advocate this style, just answers the  immediate question in the body of the Q.

Comment: @Svante thanks for commenting, I've edited the answer.